# Possibility of saving questions for later posting

Tags: support

Not sure if this is the best place to post this, but I've always wondered why the programmers.SO, or SO for that matter, does not have the option to save a question as a draft for later posting; similar to how most email clients work (Gmail, Yahoo etc.)

Is this a good idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's already there and it's 100% automatic.

See the following screen:

[image]

Your draft is automatically saved after 45 seconds.

Comment: cool :)... thought I probably missed it heh